# Alexander polynomial for knot 9-5

Tags: geometry, geometric-topology

(a) Calculate the Alexander polynomial for knot 9-5

(b) Calculate the Alexander polynomial for knot 9-5 again, this time choosing different adjacent regions to exclude from the matrix.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Do you have a question?